# How do I create a bridge interface on a raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I need a bridge interface for LXC networking to work. Normally I just do something like this:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
```

But raspbian uses dhcpcd.

How do I create a bridge on an rpi?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to setup a new bridge with no IP or with a manual IP assigned?

Comment: What  version of raspbian are you running?

Comment: Either way, I can handle the dhcp/static side of things. Generally preferred static, but on occasion dhcp. I can configure dhcpcd for either one, just can't find docs on creating br0.

Comment: Stretch 2018-06-27

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Stretch you can setup LXC like this:

(It is recommended way to separate containers to own network)

1.

```
apt install --no-install-recommends lxc libvirt-clients debootstrap libpam-cgfs lxcfs uidmap bridge-utils dnsmasq-base
```

`dnsmasq` will be used as DHCP for LXC containers/jails in 10.0.55.0/24 net

Check if everything ready:

```
lxc-checkconfig
```

If some records won't show up as "enabled" then `reboot`

2.

```
echo 'veth' >> /etc/modules
```

3.

```
insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/veth.ko
```

4.

```
echo '
### adjust and apply
echo 'USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
LXC_BRIDGE_MAC="02:01:02:03:04:05"
LXC_ADDR="10.0.55.1"
LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
LXC_NETWORK="10.0.55.0/24"
LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.55.100,10.0.55.199"
LXC_DHCP_MAX="100"
LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=""
LXC_DOMAIN=""
' >> /etc/default/lxc-net
```

With this configuration you can use static IP for jails from 10.0.55.2-99
other will pick IP from DHCP

5.

Allow forwarding:

```
echo '
# For LXC
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
systemctl restart lxc-net.service
```

6.

```
##### Add to firewall rules and apply
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.55.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.55.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -s 10.0.55.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.0.10.255 -s 10.0.10.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.0.10.1 -s 10.0.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

7.

Configure host

```
echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/80-lxc-userns.conf
sysctl --system
```

8.

Configure subuids & subgids for user that will run LXC

```
  USER=UserThatRunsLXC  # <- change
  subuids=$(cat  /etc/s*id|grep $USER)
  [ -z "${subuids}" ] && {
    usermod --add-subuids 1258512-1324047 $USER
    usermod --add-subgids 1258512-1324047 $USER
  }

  echo "$USER veth lxcbr0 10"| tee -i /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
```

If you got error message: "Permission denied - Could not access /home/$USER/.local"
then `setfacl -m u:1258512:x . .local .local/share`

9.

Configure the default template for all future LXC unprivileged containers.
**DO NOT** change `xx.xx.xx.xx` , this is MAC address template that will be generated automatically

```
cd /var/lib/lxc
mkdir -p .config/lxc

echo \
'lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf
# Subuids and subgids mapping
lxc.id_map = u 0 1258512 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 1258512 65536
# Be careful with next option to avoid security issue or lost of data
lxc.mount.auto = proc:mixed sys:ro cgroup:mixed


# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 0A:FF:xx:xx:xx:xx' >.config/lxc/default.conf
```

10.

Finally create jail (adjust to your needs):

```
Distributive=alpine
lxc-create -n NameOfyourJail -t ${Distributive} -- -r sid -a amd64
```

P.S.
If you want to use host-shared bridge instead of using NAT-ed network for containers, you can follow this link [host setup as bridge](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/SimpleBridge#Host_device_as_bridge)

Comment: I appreciate this, but I don't want to use NAT... I want to my containers to get ips on my network, just like my x86 systems running LXC do. Thank you!

Comment: Check link I just added in post scriptum how to setup host-shared bridge